# How to store/get image in PreferencesScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a preferences screen where I want a user to select an image. I do this just right. I even manage to display the image after it's selected. But, my question is this. How do I "get" the image? Like getBoolean(), getString(), etc. there is no "getImageUri" or whatever.

Here's my current code for opening the picker and assigning my own ImageView the chosen image

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.activity_settings);

    Preference prefereces = findPreference("test");
    prefereces.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
            return true;
        }
    });

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView ok = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.incognitoView);

        ok.setImageURI(selectedImage);

        Log.d("OK", "Data Recieved! " + filePath);
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot to better explain:
[image: screenshot-1]

Click "select image" brings up the Gallery Picker - actually picking an image puts the image at the center of the view, like so.

[image: screenshot-2]

Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a PreferenceClickListener, you have to implement the logic of saving/retrieving the preference yourself.

You can use a SharedPreferences.Editor to edit SharedPreferences:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("image_uri", imageUri);
editor.apply();
```

However, I would not recommend to store the image URI inside a SharedPreference, because the URI might not be accessible later. Instead, I would store the image in the file system and put a reference inside a SharedPreference.

You can read a image from URI with a ParcelFileDescriptor:

```
ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = this.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(imageUri, "r");
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
...
```

(I would move all code for saving/retrieving preference to an own class.)

```
public class MySettings {

    public static final String PREF_KEY_IMAGE_REF = "pref_image_ref";

    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    public MySettings(Context) {
        mContext = context;
        mPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public String getImageRef() {
        return mPreferences.getString(PREF_KEY_IMAGE_REF, null);
    }

    public void setImageRef(String imageRef) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_KEY_PREF_KEY_IMAGE_REF, imageRef);
        editor.apply();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok awsome. here's my next issue: https://hastebin.com/wejeqoyiye.cs - the image is not showing though! As you can see, my imageUri is being passed accurately.

Comment: As I said, don't save the URI in a SharedPreference. Read the image in onActivityResult, write it to the file system and save a reference (e.g. the file name) in a SharedPreference.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how to write this to the file system?

Comment: There are some examples on StackOverflow. (See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585263/save-file-to-internal-memory-in-android) (Use my example to read the file using a ParcelFileDescriptor.)