# How to move a file to Internal Storage (reserved app's memory) in Android with Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, stream, android-internal-storage

Despite the title, very similar to other ones in Stack Overflow, no one of the possibilities I met seems to suits well for me.

I am downloading a file with DownloadManager (I chose this way due to the fact I'm new to android and kotlin and it seemed to me quicket to download a file through DM and then copy it into internal storage + delete it from Download folder, than manually managing the threads creation to handle the download directly into internal storage).

Then I'm trying to move it into internal storage.
The files can be images but mainly mp3 files. Now I'm developing the mp3 reader part.
The download is ok, but the I've got issues about copying the file into the interal storage
Here's my code:

```
if(myDownloadKind == "I"){ // string "I" stands for "internal"

    println("myTag - into BroadCast for inner")

    var myStoredFile:String = uri.toString()
    println("mytag - myStoredFile: $myStoredFile")
    // here I try to convert the mp3 file into a ByteArray to copy it
    var data:ByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(myStoredFile))
    println("myTag - data: $data")

    var myOutputStream: FileOutputStream
    // write file in internal storage
    try {
        myOutputStream = context.openFileOutput(myStoredFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        myOutputStream.write(data) // NOT WORKING!!
    }catch (e: Exception){
        e.printStackTrace() 
    }


} else if (myDownloadKind == "E"){
  // now this doesn't matter, Saving in external storage is ok
}
```

I really cannot find an entry-level (for noob!) documentation so I'm struggling with a very simple thing, I guess...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint! :) I did't know it was just reversed on itself

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I managed to fix my trouble. 
I put here the link to the answer which saved my day (finally I found it): [save file to internal memory in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585263/save-file-to-internal-memory-in-android)

I simply changed (just to mantain the copy from External Storage) the InputStream source making it pointing at my own file!
Also I finally understood the "InputStream system" and, of course, I rewrote the while loop in a Kotlin-esque way

```
try {
    println("myTag - into BroadCast for inner")

    val downloadedFile = File(uri.toString())
    val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(downloadedFile)
    println("myTag - input stream of file: $fileInputStream")

    val inputStream = fileInputStream
    val inStream = BufferedInputStream(inputStream, 1024 * 5)

    val file = File(context.getDir("Music", Context.MODE_PRIVATE), "/$myFilename$myExtensionVar")
    println("myTag - my cavolo di file: $file")

    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete()
    }
    file.createNewFile()

    val outStream = FileOutputStream(file)
    val buff = ByteArray(5 * 1024)

    var len = 0
    while(inStream.read(buff).also { len = it } >= 0){
        outStream.write(buff, 0, len)
    }

    outStream.flush()
    outStream.close()
    inStream.close()

} catch (e: Exception) {
    e.printStackTrace()
}
```

I think, however, I will simply download the file directly into the internal storage.